# Given three equal length arrays, how can i find the number of possible combinations where i pick an integer from each array in an increasing fashion

Tags: arrays, algorithm, loops, iteration

Say I have three arrays of *n* length:

```
first = [19, 29, 60];
second = [20, 12, 30];
third = [26, 60, 90];
```

Without iterating through three nested loops, what is the best way to find the total number of possible combinations where i can pick an integer from the first array, then a bigger one from the second, then a bigger one from the third. Essentially, one combination is:

```
first[i] < second[j] < third[k]
for example: 19 < 30 < 90 or 29 < 30 < 60
```

The total number of combinations in the example above is 7. What is the most efficient way to get this number?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sort all arrays  *(complexity O(NlogN) for array length N)*

For every item `B[i]` of the second array get number of lesser items in the first array `L` and number of bigger items in the third array `R`

Add `L*R` to the result

*(linear complexity, because `L` can only increase with `i` increasing and `R` can only decrease)*

Pseudocode for the second stage:

```
 ia = 0
 ic = 0
 for ib in range(N):
     while (A[ia] < B[ib]):
         ia++
     while (C[ic] <= B[ib]):
         ic++
     result += ia * (N - ic)
```

Overall complexity is `O(NlogN)`

Comment: Maybe you should provide some details on how to do the second step in linear time.

Comment: It seems to me that the second step is also O(NlogN), but the overall complexity remains the same.

Comment: Indeed, I think the same. There might be a linear approach to do it but it is slightly more involved. Still the complexity would remain the same by the first step.

Comment: @Razvan Socol We don't need to make binary search to find L and R at every step of the second stage - note that the second array is sorted too.

Comment: @MBo thank you for the advice. After sorting, for each value in the second array, I reverse looped through the first array until i found L[j] < B[i], then added the number of values below j to 'count1'. I did the same for the third array (looping in the i++ direction), and adding any values left after the first B[i] < R[k] to 'count2'. At the end i multiplied count1 and count2 like you said, and received the correct answer. I assume this is the method you had in mind? Either way, excellent solution! :)

Comment: @Andrej Butić Yes, I meant this method. Added pseudocode (not tested)